# Move the spinner arrow to the left close to the text

Tags: android, spinner

When I select a new position, my hand is away from the text. I want to switch after the arrow is close to the text with a slight indentation. I fasten the picture of how it looks now, and what I want to achieve, as well as an example of my code. If it is possible to achieve what I want, please tell me

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:dropDownWidth="220dp"/>
```

[image]